# Error creating a Crosstab in Python. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a Crosstab and I'm getting the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

I have already including parenthesis and brackets, but nothing works.

This is the code

```
y1 = np.array([df_train[df_train['dep_delayed_15min'] == 'Y']['UniqueCarrier'].value_counts().values])
y2 = np.array([df_train[df_train['dep_delayed_15min'] == 'N']['UniqueCarrier'].value_counts().values])
y3 = y1+y2
y4 = y1/y3
y5 = y2/y3
y6 = set(df_train['UniqueCarrier'])

d = {'UniqueCarrier': [y6], 'Perc_Y': [y4], 'Perc_N': [y5]}
df = pd.DataFrame([d])

df.head()

pd.crosstab[df['UniqueCarrier'], df['Perc_Y'], df['Perc_N']]
```

This is what I get form df.head() that is not what I need for the next step, that is creating the crosstab with the numbers.

```
    UniqueCarrier   Perc_Y  Perc_N
0   [{CO, FL, UA, DH, NW, B6, AS, DL, HP, EV, AA, ...   [[[0.21343323166688768, 0.1879379910809089, 0....   [[[0.7865667683331123, 0.8120620089190911, 0.8...
```

Comment: The post title says the error is "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable", but the post body says the error is "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple".  Which is it?

Comment: You're right, sorry for the confusion, the error is   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: @Junior Try this code: `pd.crosstab[[df['UniqueCarrier'], df['Perc_Y'], df['Perc_N']]]`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, pitifully the error continues :(

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm very confused pd.crosstab is a function so should be invoked with parentheses

```
pd.crosstab(df['UniqueCarrier'], df['Perc_Y'], df['Perc_N'])
```

Comment: Hi SimonN, that gives me the error 
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Could you please post the whole trace so we can see what it says about where the error is occurring?

Comment: Of Course, there it goes---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-8b94fd787f3e> in <module>
      9 df = pd.DataFrame([d])
     10 #df.head()
---> 11 pd.crosstab(df['UniqueCarrier'], df['Perc_Y'], df['Perc_N'])

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: When I replace set for np.unique in the sentence, like this

y6 = np.unique(df_train['UniqueCarrier'])

I get this error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-149-cc2ae8b14fac> in <module>
      9 df = pd.DataFrame([d])
     10 #df.head()
---> 11 pd.crosstab(df['UniqueCarrier'], df['Perc_Y'], df['Perc_N'])

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable